# Event Not Firing Properly within Storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, animation

I have a custom `UserControl` which needs to be scaled on X from 1 to 0, and then back from 0 to 1 using the following coded `Storyboard`:

```
Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

DoubleAnimation animationFlipBegin = new DoubleAnimation();
animationFlipBegin.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.4D);
animationFlipBegin.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1D);
animationFlipBegin.To = 0D;
animationFlipBegin.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetProperty, myUserControl);
animationFlipBegin.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, BuildPropertyPath("(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));

DoubleAnimation animationFlipEnd = new DoubleAnimation();
animationFlipEnd.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5D);
animationFlipEnd.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1D);
animationFlipEnd.To = 1D;
animationFlipEnd.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetProperty, myUserControl);
animationFlipEnd.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, BuildPropertyPath("(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));

storyboard.Children.Add(animationFlipBegin);
storyboard.Children.Add(animationFlipEnd);
storyboard.Begin();
```

When it reaches ScaleX value of 0, a function must be called on that `UserControl`. So my first attempt was to add the followin code:

```
animationFlipBegin.Completed = new EventHandler(DoAction);

private void DoAction(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myUserControl.DoAction();
}
```

The problem is that `DoAction` is called only after the `Storyboard` is completed and not when the `DoubleAnimation` is completed, probably due to threading... which is absolutely not good for me!

So... my second attempt was to modify my custom `UserControl` code as follows:

```
<UserControl.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <ScaleTransform Core:Name="Scaling" Changed="OnScaleChanged"/>

private void OnScaleChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Scale.ScaleX == 0D)
        DoAction();
}
```

Looked like a smart idea initially, but it's not. `ScaleTransform.Changed` only gets called sometimes and it's never called when `ScaleX` is 0, from what I saw debugging my code.

So... the only solution I can still figure out is to split my `Storyboard` into two separate `Storyboard`, and then call the `DoAction` event after the first one is completed. It's soooo ugly to see and I would really like to find another way. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you run the animations separately without a Storyboard? Just start the second animation in the `Completed` handler of the first one, without a `BeginTime`.

```
var animationFlipBegin = new DoubleAnimation
{
    BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.4),
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1),
    To = 0
};

var animationFlipEnd = new DoubleAnimation
{
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1),
    To = 1
};

var scaleTransform = (ScaleTransform)((TransformGroup)RenderTransform).Children[1];

animationFlipBegin.Completed +=
    (o, e) =>
    {
        DoAction();
        scaleTransform.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, animationFlipEnd);
    };

scaleTransform.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, animationFlipBegin);
```